# Generate a second follow up Event with delay for each Event with Rx

Tags: c#, .net, linq, system.reactive

Currently I am looking into handling MIDI messages with the reactive framework.

When generating a NoteOn event it must follow a NoteOff event. So what would be the best way to send a second event after each NoteOn with a certain delay?

Something like:

```
//pseudo code
var noteOnObservable = GetNoteOns();
var noteOffObservable = noteOnObservable.ForEach(e => new NoteOffMessage(e.MidiNote))
     .Delay(e => GetDelay(e));
var notes = noteOnObservable.Merge(noteOffObservable);
```

Where both NoteOn and NoteOff messages are of the same type `MidiMessage`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty much exactly as you had it. Ideally you would publish `noteOnObservable` so you don't have multiple subscriptions:

```
var noteOnObservable = GetNoteOns().Publish().RefCount();
var noteOffObservable = noteOnObservable
    .Select(e => new NoteOffMessage(e.MidiNote))
    .Delay(e => GetDelay(e));
var notes = noteOnObservable.Merge(noteOffObservable);
```

You didn't describe what type `GetDelay` returns. If it returns a `TimeSpan`, so you'll have to convert that to an observable. If you can in `GetDelay` that works. If not, then you can do this:

```
var noteOnObservable = GetNoteOns().Publish().RefCount();
var noteOffObservable = noteOnObservable
    .Select(e => new NoteOffMessage(e.MidiNote))
    .Delay(e => Observable.Timer(GetDelay(e)));
var notes = noteOnObservable.Merge(noteOffObservable);
```

Comment: Didn't know that i was so close. Thanks for the Publish().RefCount() improvement. That GetDelay is not yet specified... that's the next task. Would the Observable.Timer work for an individual delay per event?

Comment: Yes it would. If you wanted to specify a static `TimeSpan` (uniform for all events), then you could just do `.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100))` or whatever the appropriate time was.

Comment: @Shlomo - a slightly neater approach is to do it like this: `var notes = GetNoteOns().Publish(gnos => gnos.Merge(gnos.Select(e => new NoteOffMessage(e.MidiNote)).Delay(e => GetDelay(e))));`.